# Mongoid 1.month.ago is returning 01 for 1st of March

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a ROR app: ruby 2.3.0, rails 4.2.5.1 and mongoid 5.0, and in one of my models I have :
field :statement_month, default: 1.month.ago.strftime('%m') , but only on 1st of March it saves a wrong result: "01" instead of "02" .
I have no problems for other months in first day of the month.
I also added some logs, before_create and after_create , printing:
"-------1_month_ago_month------------------------" + 1.month.ago.strftime('%m') => in logs it show "02" but in DB object is "01". It is a mongoid issue, or maybe a TimeZone issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for dynamic defaults uses Procs. See https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#defaults.

MongoDB stores times as UTC timestamps, your program does not explicitly convert to UTC thus it is 1) potentially misbehaving with respect to time zones and 2) potentially misbehaving with respect to daylight savings time. Date math generally must be explicitly performed in either local time (and you should know the time zone you are operating in) or in UTC. Mixing the two eventually causes problems.

To troubleshoot the wrong month, set your system time to March 1 and debug the program. In particular, try March 1 01:00 and March 1 23:00. Those are often different dates in UTC for the same local date.

Comment: The solution was to change the old code from:

field :statement_month, default: 1.month.ago.strftime('%m') to 

  field :statement_month, default: -> { (Time.now - 1.month).strftime('%m') }